# If $S$ is a unital commutative ring, and $R$ is a subring with unity $1_R = 1_S$, is it the case that $R[x]$ is an $S$-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

If $S$ is a commutative ring, and $R$ is a subring with unity $1_R = 1_S$, is it the case that $R[x]$ is an $S$-algebra?

I don´t see why this would be true; I asked GPT-$3.5$ and it gave me $f:S \to R[x]$ defined by $$f(s) = s \cdot r(x) \quad (s \in S, r(x) \in R[x])$$ but I fail to see why this would be in $$R[x].$$ Since $R$ is a subring, it is not neccessarily closed under multiplication from elements $s \in S$ (cf. ideals), hence this can not be generally true.

My reason for asking this, is that I want to show that $$S \otimes_{R} R[x]$$ is an $S$-algebra. There is a theorem that says that *if* both $S$ and $N$ are S-algebras, then $$S \otimes_{S} N$$ is an $S$-algebra, and then you get "for free" an explicit definition of the $S$-algebra on this tensor-product.

Edit: It is (quite) clear to me that $$S \otimes_{R} R[x]$$ is an $R$-algebra by the map $$r \overset{\varphi}{\mapsto} r(1_S \otimes 1_S) = \varphi_1(r) \otimes 1_S = 1_S \otimes \varphi_2(r)$$ where $$\varphi_1,\varphi_2$$ are the from the $R$-algebras $$(S,\varphi_1:R \to S)$$ and $$(R[x],\varphi_2:R \to R[x]).$$

But I am unsure how to define an $S$-algebra on $S \otimes_{R} R[x]$.

If someone could provide how $$f:S → S \otimes_{R} R[x]$$ in the $S$-algebra $$(S \otimes_{R} R[x],f)$$ is defined, I’d be thankful.

Comment: Of course ChatGPT is hallucinating again.

Comment: No, it's not true. Try with $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: ChatGPT is often bad at detecting when plausible-sounding things are false! In this case $R[x]$ definitely doesn't need to be an $S$-algebra. You should just try and get stuck right in with the tensor product you're interested in - given an element of $S$, what possible canonical choices of element of the tensor product are there? Or alternatively, does the tensor product have any subrings that look a bit like $S$? The point of this construction is to turn something that's not an $S$-algebra into an $S$-algebra by tensoring with $S$ and "extending the scalars".

Comment: "There is a theorem that says that if both $S$ and $N$ are $S$-algebras, then $S \otimes_{S} N$ is an $S$-algebra" - Of course, $S$ is always an $S$-algebra, and $S \otimes_{S} N$ is always isomorphic to $N$. Perhaps, you meant to instead say that "if both $M$ and $N$ are $S$-algebras, then $M \otimes_{S} N$ is an $S$-algebra"?

Comment: Yes, bad notational choice there, thanks Geoffrey. Also, I see that this would not really help, since what I really want to show is that $$S \otimes_{R} R[x]$$ is an $S$-algebra, not $$S \otimes_{S} R[x].$$ 

Can someone point out how one defines this $S$-algebra, or how one can see it as an $S$-algebra?

Comment: Quite apart from writing college essays, it's amazing that while people successfully use chatgpt for programming, chatgpt is so v. bad in math.  The best example I've seen so far, is on the one hand providing the reasonable answer of $3 \cdot(1/6)\cdot (5/6)^2$ as the probability of seeing 1 exactly once on three throws of a dice,  and then eventually calculating the first product $3\cdot(1/6)$ as $3/36 $ i.e., weirdly distributing the $3$ into both denominator and numerator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have indicated, it is not the case in general that $R[X]$ is an $S$-algebra. The good news is that you don't actually need this to show what you really want to show, which is that $S \otimes_{R} R[X]$ is an $S$-algebra.

To show this, we need to exhibit a ring homomorphism $S \to S \otimes_{R} R[X]$. I claim that the map $\varphi \colon S \to S \otimes_{R} R[X]$ given by $s \mapsto s \otimes 1$ is a ring homomorphism. The details of verifying this are straightforward, and I leave them to you.

Instead, I'd like to take a moment to point out that in this case, this $S$-algebra structure is actually a bit less mysterious than you seem to think. Indeed, consider the $R$-bilinear map $S \times R[X] \to S[X]$ which sends a pair $s \in S, f(X) = a_{n}X^{n} + \cdots + a_{1}X + a_{0} \in R[X]$ to $sa_{n}X^{n}+sa_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\cdots+sa_{1}X+sa_{0}$. By the universal property of the tensor product, this descends to an $R$-linear map $\psi \colon S \otimes_{R} R[X] \to S[X]$ which sends the simple tensor $s \otimes f(X)$ to $sa_{n}X^{n}+sa_{n-1}X^{n-1}+\cdots+sa_{1}X+sa_{0}$.

You can further verify that $\psi$ is multiplicative (check on simple tensors and then use linearity to get the rest), and so $\psi$ is a morphism of $R$-algebras. In fact, equipping $S[X]$ with the "usual" $S$-algebra structure given by the inclusion $i \colon S \to S[X]$, you can check that $\psi$ is a morphism of $S$-algebras, i.e. $\psi \circ \varphi = i$.

Perhaps surprisingly, $\psi$ is actually an **iso**morphism of $S$-algebras. I think the easiest way to see this is to just write down the inverse map. Recall that for any $S$-algebra $T$, and any element $t \in T$, there is a unique $S$-algebra morphism $S[X] \to T$ which sends $X$ to $t$. Indeed, the image of $X$ determines an $S$-algebra morphism $S[X] \to T$ completely by using $S$-linearity and multiplicativity, so if such a morphism exists, it must be unique. On the other hand, you can check that the map $S[X] \to T$ which sends $s_{n}X^{n} + \cdots s_{1}X + s_{0}$ to $s_{n}t^{n} + \cdots + s_{1}t+s_{0}$ is a perfectly well-defined $S$-algebra homomorphism. (This is a great exercise if you haven't done this before.)

Using this, we can just write down the inverse to $\psi$: it's the universal morphism of $S$-algebras $\tau \colon S[X] \to S \otimes_{R} R[X]$ which sends $X$ to $1 \otimes X$. Therefore, the $S$-algebra structure I defined above on $S \otimes_{R} R[X]$ is in some sense "the same" as the $S$-algebra structure $S[X]$, where "the same" can be precisely interpreted as exhibiting the $S$-algebra isomorphism $\psi$ we defined above.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I had a similar idea, which I tried, but I did not flesh it out as fully as you did. Very good. I am unsure by what property it is the case that if we have unique $S$-algebra $T$, then there is a unique $S$-algebra homomorphism $$S[X] \to T$$ which sends $X$ to $t$. I think I see why it is completely determined by where it sends $X$. But, by what property do we know that such a map exists?

Comment: @Ben123 careful with the quantifiers in the statement there. What I had said was: for any $S$-algebra $T$ and any fixed $t \in T$, there is a unique $S$-algebra homomorphism $S[X] \to T$ which sends $X$ to $t$. Anyway, we are not using any abstract properties to produce this map. See the last sentence of the fifth paragraph in my answer, where I write down explicitly what the map is. You can (and should!) check yourself that this is a ring homomorphism - happy to help if you get stuck.